# What does 可愛い mean here?

Tags: meaning

The panel below discusses what happens to actors when they don't get deeply involved in their role.

[image]

I am uncertain about the meaning of the word 可愛い in the last panel. I think it means something like "pitiful", synonymous with かわいそう?

Comment: It's almost always followed by もの, or reduced もん, in this usage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When 可愛い is used to describe a troublesome or dangerous thing, it means "less severe", "relatively easier to deal with" or "can be considered trivial". In this sense, even a scary gang or disease can be described as 可愛い!

> #### [かわいい](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%84_%28%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%29/)
>
> 物事の規模が小さいさま。程度が軽いさま。

This is usually used when the speaker is comparing it to an even bigger trouble/problem/danger. (e.g., AはかわいいものだがBは嫌だ; Bは困るけどAくらいならかわいいよね).

Examples:

- 彼の遅刻なんて可愛いものだよ。チームにはもっと大きな問題がある。
  His tardiness is trivial. Our team has much bigger problems.
- この先生が出す試験問題としては、こんなの可愛い方ですって。
  As far as this teacher's exam questions go, this one is on the easier side!